# Content Type not showing up in the consuming site after publishing from hub site

Tags: content

We have a SP Online environment with a content type hub to handle all content types.We have created some new content type in the hub site and  completed all the necessary steps to publish  it .but still we are not getting these content type  as option to add in other sites.

we waited for a day ,still it is not appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Navigate to: {https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test}/_layouts/15/contenttypesyndicationhubs.aspx

Check Refresh all published content types on next update.

[image]

and press OK. Then republish your content types from your content type hub.

---

One other way of doing the same with code and CSOM is to empty the value of the propertybag item "metadatatimestamp". This will perform the same thing as above. (Source: [How To Do Refresh All Published Content Types On Next Update In Content Type Hub In SharePoint Office 365 Programmatically (CSOM)](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-do-refresh-all-published-content-types-on-next-update-in-Content-Type-Hub-in-SharePoint-Office-365-Programmatically-(CSOM)))

Comment: We have already done these steps ,still facing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Just following on from above, should the Sharepoint site be a Teams private channel based site, you will need to enable the hidden site collection feature for the Content Type publishing via PnP powershell as per below (unfortunately this feature is missed when a Teams private channel based site is created):

Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://(tenant).sharepoint.com/sites/(sitename) -Interactive

Enable-PnPFeature -Identity 73ef14b1-13a9-416b-a9b5-ececa2b0604c -Scope Site -Force

Then following the above, you can opt to do the forced refresh from the 'Content type publishing' option under the Site Collection Administration section from the site settings.